# Proving that $d((x_n),(y_n)) := 2 ^{−\min \{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \neq y_n \} }$ defines a metric on $S$, $S$ being the set of $0-1$ sequence..

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Mm currently struggling to prove the statement in the title. I'm aware of how a metric is defined but i have no clue how to prove this.
Here is the whole problem, but better readable:

Let $S := \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} $ the set of $0-1$ sequences.
Prove that $d((x_n),(y_n)) := 2 ^{−\min \{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \neq y_n \} }$ defines a metric on S.

Found nothing that could help to solve this problem on the internet.
I'd be very thankfull for help on this topic :)

Best regards

Comment: I attempted to fix editing. But still it does not make sense. Please clarify what $S$ represents. If possible, latex it.

Comment: $S$ is the space of sequences of $0$s and $1$s.

Comment: Yes, that question is pretty much the same as mine. Thanks Oliver :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!:~)

To make the definition rigorous you need to define what happens to $d(,)$ when $\forall n ,x_n=y_n$ (same sequence). Let's assume in that case you set $\min \{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \neq y_n \} =\infty$, and we understand $2^{-\infty}=0$. (this is sloppy, but it should be solved at the definition.)

If that's the case then we got

1. Identity $d((x_n),(x_n))=0$ we get this for free from definition above.
2. Symmetry, this is also obvious, since $\neq$ is symmetric $d((y_n),(x_n))= 2 ^{−\min \{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \neq y_n \} }
   =d((x_n),(y_n))$
3. Triangle inequality. Assume $(x_n),(y_n),(z_n)$, prove $d((z_n),(x_n))\leq d((y_n),(x_n))+d((y_n),(z_n))$

First, if two sequences match $(y_n)=(x_n)$ or $(y_n)=(z_n)$, then using the already proved symmetry and identity, the triangle inequality holds.

Otherwise, let $p=\min \{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \neq y_n \}$, $q=\min \{n \in \mathbb{N}: z_n \neq y_n \}$, $p,q$ are finite integers. $(x_n),(y_n)$ match in their first $p-1$ "digits", $(z_n),(y_n)$ match in their first $q-1$ "digits"

Without loss of generality, let $p\leq q$. Then, $\forall n\leq p-1, x_n=y_n=z_n$.

Thus the first "digit" $(z_n),(x_n)$ differs is at least at $p$ $$\min \{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \neq z_n \}\geq p$$
Thus
$$
d((z_n),(x_n))\leq2^{-p} < 2^{-p} + 2^{-q}=d((y_n),(x_n))+d((y_n),(z_n))
$$
Thus we proved triangle inequality.

We prove that $d$ is a metric with the 3 conditions in the definition.

Comment: Hey, cool i think i got how to proof works :)